# How to "sort" a dictionary by number of occurrences of a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of values that gives the number of occurrences of a value in a list. How can I return a new dictionary that divides the former dictionary into separate dictionaries based on the value?

In other words, I want to sort this dictionary:

```
>>> a = {'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':4, 'D':2, 'E':3}
```

to this one.

```
b = {2: {'A', 'D'}, 3: {'B', 'E'}, 4: {'C'}}
```

How do I approach the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 2, 'E': 3}

b = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in a.items():
    b[v].add(k)
```

This is what you'll get:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {2: {'D', 'A'}, 3: {'B', 'E'}, 4: {'C'}})
```

You can convert `b` to a normal dict afterwards with `b = dict(b)`.

Comment: There is no need to convert it to `dict` explicitly. It behaves like normal dictionary :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Not necessarily. As an example, trying to access a missing key adds an entry to the `defaultdict`, so you get `True` if you check whether that key is in the dictionary later on, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you are a python beginner like me, you probably wanna try this

a = {'A': 2 , 'B': 3 , 'C' : 4 , 'D' : 2, 'E' : 3}

b = {}

for key in a:

```
lst = []

new_key = a[key]

if new_key not in b:

    lst.append(key)

    b[new_key] = lst

else:

    b[new_key].append(key)
```

print(b)

It uses the mutable property of python dictionary to achieve the result you want.